# Edit table in CakePHP 2: Update/Insert error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Problem: When editing an entry SQL is making an INSERT instead of an UPDATE.

I have two SQL tables : users and users_detail.
`users(id,role,name,password)` &
`users_detail(id,adress,city,user_id)`

Foreign key `users_detail.user_id` is linked to `users.id`.

I have a form in my cakephp app to edit users_detail, if a user wants to edit his adress for example.
Here is my controller :

```
        public function admin_edit_dashboard($id = null){
    if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid user details');
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

        if ($this->User->UserDetail->save($this->request->data, true, ['id', 'address', 'city'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user has been saved');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'dashboard'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    } else {
        //$this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        $user = $this->User->UserDetail->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'UserDetail.user_id' => $id
            )
        ));
        $this->request->data = $user;
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

And my form :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('UserDetail');?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('address', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        <br />
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('city', array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
        <br />
        <?php echo $this->Form->button('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

But when I'm validate the form to edit details I have an error :

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Because the SQL query isn't an UPDATE but an INSERT. I don't know why.

> SQL Query: INSERT INTO `cake`.`user_details`
>   (`adress_ex`, `city_ex`) VALUES ('roses street',
>   'London')

Thank you!

**EDIT : It works, thanks for your help! Good code added.**

Comment: In what controller is `admin_edit_dashboard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have several problems.

`$this->request->address` is in correct. Form data is passed as `$this->request->data` so you should be using `$this->request->data['UserDetail']['address']` *etc*.

If you want to make sure you only save specific fields you can pass these as the third parameter of `save()` and then you don't need to use `set()` beforehand:-

```
$this->UserDetail->save($this->request->data, true, ['id', 'address', 'city']);
```

The SQL error implies that your primary key on the `user_details` table is not set to auto-increment (which it should). Which is why an `INSERT` fails.

You are also forgetting to pass the primary key for the record you're trying to update so Cake assumes you want to create a new record. Make sure you include this so that Cake knows to use `UPDATE`. For example include the following in your View form:-

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for all your advices, it works now! I'm going to edit my first to show the right code. Perfect with skywalker's advices.

Answer (score 2):

Your `User` model should have association to `UserDetail` like:

```
public $hasOne = array('UserDetail');
```

and your in `UserDetail`:

```
public $belongsTo = array('User');
```

Then you don't have to use `loadModel`, just do:

```
$this->User->UserDetail->find('first', array(...));
```

And you should edit user details from `UserDetailsController` action.

In your view add lines to know what you are editing:

```
echo $this->Form->input('id');
```

And then just do save with passed `$this->request->data`. That should do it. And like I said, check table id in database, it has to be autoincrement.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have updated my code and my first post.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, it helped my a lot with drmonkeyninja's solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can't update just your table by telling in controller

```
$this->UserDetail->save($this->request->data)
```

Instead you should try to do something like

```
//find that specific row in database and then update columns and save it

$this->UserDetail->set(array('address'=>$request->address,'city'=>$request->city));                
$this->UserDetail->save();
```

Your model wants to save it like a new `user_details` under `id = 0` which already exists because you didn't specify that you want to update it and which columns you want to update.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it helps! But now my fields are detected as blank. They aren't validated. I don't know why. I have updated my post to show you my new code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try now, i have updated my code because i didn't knew the "names" of your input field from form

Comment: Thanks for your advices, it helped my a lot!